# C++ exception not propagating when non-empty function

Tags: c++

I have the following function:

```
void filesys::create(char * pathname, char type) {
    //char * msg;
    //sprintf(msg, "create pathname: %s type: %c", pathname, type);
    throw filesys::BadRequest();    
}
```

When the first two lines are commented out as shown, the exception propagates and is caught by the calling function. When I uncomment these lines, I immediately get a propagation error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type filesys::BadRequest: bad req
```

Exception definition within filesys class:

```
struct BadRequest : public std::exception {
    const char * what () const throw () {
        return "bad req";
    }
};
```

Catch block:

```
try {
    char * response = serve_request(decrypted);
    send_msg(connectionfd, response);
} catch (filesys::BadRequest& e) {
    cout << "hello?";
}
```

Comment: Not sure, if it would solve the issue, but: `filesys::BadRequest& e` -> `filesys::BadRequest const& e`?

Comment: shouldn't be directly related, but you should catch by `const&` because there's no point in having a modifiable reference to an exception object.... or maybe it is related actually, if the rvalue you throw can't bind to a non-const ref. Shrug; one should be `const`-correct in any case.

Comment: `msg` is uninitialized. Using it as buffer for `sprintf` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @churill's suggestion was the root of my problem. Thank you!